# Is there an XEmbed equivalent in Windows?

Tags: windows

[XEmbed](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html) is used to embed an X11 window in an other application. This is done by reparenting the target window.

Is there a windows equivalent to be able to embed an external window into an other one? In my case, I have control on both applications/windows so cooperation is possible.

Answer (score 2):

[OLE Compound Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms693383%28VS.85%29.aspx) provides the ability for one application to implement part of another applications document (eg. embed a spreadsheet inside a word processor).

But COM etc. is a big learning curve.